# как удалить кнопкой мыши элемент li?

Tags: javascript

мне нужно по нажатию лкм на выбранный элемент li его удалить, а следующий элемент встал на место удаленного

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  const btn_Hobbies = document.getElementById('buttonHobbies'),
        input_Hobbies = document.getElementById('hobbies');

  btn_Hobbies.addEventListener('click', () => {

      if (input_Hobbies.value.length > 0) {
        let newLi = document.createElement('li');
          newLi.innerHTML = input_Hobbies.value;
          list.insertBefore(newLi, list.children[0]);
          }
    });

    // удаление интереса

});
```

```html
  <div class="div_hobbies">
  <label for="hobbies">Интересы</label>
  <input type="text" class="inputHobbies" id="hobbies" placeholder="Ваш интерес?" name="" value="">
  <input type="button" id ="buttonHobbies" name="" value="Добавить интерес">
  </div>
  <ul id = "list">
  </ul>
  </form>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

как то так

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  const btn_Hobbies = document.getElementById('buttonHobbies'),
        input_Hobbies = document.getElementById('hobbies'),
        itemsList = document.getElementById('list');

  btn_Hobbies.addEventListener('click', () => {

      if (input_Hobbies.value.length > 0) {
        let newLi = document.createElement('li');
          newLi.innerHTML = input_Hobbies.value;
          list.insertBefore(newLi, list.children[0]);
          }
    });
    
   itemsList.addEventListener('click', function(event){
      let target = event.target;
      if(target.tagName === 'LI') {
        //Удаляем
        target.remove();
      }
      
   });


});
```

```html
<div class="div_hobbies">
  <label for="hobbies">Интересы</label>
  <input type="text" class="inputHobbies" id="hobbies" placeholder="Ваш интерес?" name="" value="">
  <input type="button" id ="buttonHobbies" name="" value="Добавить интерес">
  </div>
  <ul id = "list">
  </ul>
  </form>
  </div>
```

Comment: но ведь это именно скрыть, а не удалить, а мне надо удалить его из списка. это как запасной вариант можно оставить, но хотелось бы всё-таки удалить

Comment: @СотниЛичностей поправил

Answer (score 2):

Так? (код не трогал, только добавил строчку удаления)

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  const btn_Hobbies = document.getElementById('buttonHobbies'),
        input_Hobbies = document.getElementById('hobbies');

  btn_Hobbies.addEventListener('click', () => {

      if (input_Hobbies.value.length > 0) {
        let newLi = document.createElement('li');
          newLi.innerHTML = input_Hobbies.value;
          list.insertBefore(newLi, list.children[0]);
          /*Добавил только эту строчку*/
          newLi.addEventListener('click', function(){ this.remove(); });
          }
    });
});
```

```html
<div class="div_hobbies">
  <label for="hobbies">Интересы</label>
  <input type="text" class="inputHobbies" id="hobbies" placeholder="Ваш интерес?" name="" value="">
  <input type="button" id ="buttonHobbies" name="" value="Добавить интерес">
</div>
<ul id = "list">
</ul>
```